# Product Render RGB Lightning Setup

Tags: rendering, motion-blur

Does someone know how to make this RGB lightning blur on a fan in Blender? Or you suppose to do it in another software? Does it have to do something with motion blur setup?
Thank you in advance:-)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start by making a fan "spiral" on the faces you want to be a fan. The spiral is accomplished by using the Z coordinate (isolated) from a Spherical Gradient Texture as the input vector for a Radial Gradient Texture. The Fraction Node turns it into "steps" (blades) and the Multiply determines how many (number of blades). Note that the texture has to "line up" properly, so adjust your multiply value accordingly.

[image: Fan1]

To give the illusion of "jittery movement", add a Wave texture after the Radial Gradient, and give it the same fraction/multiply treatment. This will give a bunch of uneven lines in the "Swirl" mix the 2 with a Noise texture to make the "movement" more apparent in some areas than others.

[image: Fan2]

Multiply this whole thing over your background color - Make sure to use a noise texture (and a ColorRamp) to obscure most of the "fan blades" from the mix - the less you see, the faster your brain thinks it's "moving". Run the mix through an emission texture and turn on Bloom for extra effect (the glow helps the blur effect):

[image: Fan3]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! Thank you for taking time to answer in length:-)
Top!

Answer (score 0):

### version 01

One quick ... *Emission* shader directly to blades with *Gradient Texture* > **Radial**

[image]
[image]

Enable **Motion Blur** ...

[image]

### version_02

One more natural effect - To light blades add two rings (with the same material as above in version 01) ... under Object Properties > **Visibility > Camera** - disable it.

[image]

For blades add **Translucent** shader ...

[image]
[image]

And again render with Motion Blur ...

[image]

Model original taken from https://skfb.ly/o76tH

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the responser! Top answer!!!